# Property 'attributeMapFailedPasswordAnswerLockoutTime' cannot be mapped to schema attribute 'lockoutTime' as the attribute is already in use

Tags: active-directory, adam, activedirectorymembership

I am trying to use the ADMembershipProvider to connect to a local ADAM server and I am getting the error in the title. If I remove the enable password reset and the properties it relies on I am able to connect.

I have tried to google it and nothing has come up. Below is my provider config.  Any advice would be highly appreciated.

```
<providers>
    <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=3.5.0.0,               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
      connectionStringName="ADService"
      connectionUsername="[username]"
      connectionPassword="[password]"
      connectionProtection="Secure"
      enableSearchMethods="true"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      applicationName="/"
      description="Default AD connection"
      requiresUniqueEmail="true"
      clientSearchTimeout="30"
      serverSearchTimeout="30"
      attributeMapPasswordQuestion="department"
      attributeMapPasswordAnswer="division"
      attributeMapFailedPasswordAnswerCount="badPwdCount"
      attributeMapFailedPasswordAnswerTime="badPasswordTime"
      attributeMapFailedPasswordAnswerLockoutTime="lockoutTime"
      attributeMapEmail = "mail"
      attributeMapUsername = "userPrincipalName"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts = "5"
      passwordAttemptWindow = "10"
      passwordAnswerAttemptLockoutDuration = "30"
      minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"/>
  </providers>
```

FYI... The closest thing to a similar result was someone who got this error on a similar attribute and he just restarted the machine.  That didn't work for me. I did find this article as well http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dansellers/archive/2005/10/20/483272.aspx but I am struggling to get the LDAP admin to make this change. Especially since we already have those properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had the LDAP admin perform the steps in the following link an we are up and running.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dansellers/archive/2005/10/20/483272.aspx